# Weierstrass's M-test example for uniform convergence and switching Sum and Integral.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, riemann-zeta

How would I go about finding $M_n$ in

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^\infty x^{\frac{s}{2}-1}e^{-\pi n^{2}x}dx
\end{equation}
to show that it is uniformly convergent?

**UPDATE:**
Just coming back to this and having trouble understanding this. Without relating this integral  to the zeta and gamma functions, how do I show the sum has uniform convergence ( Weierstrass)? For $Re(s) > 1$. And can therefore swap integral with summation by fubinis theorem?

Comment: Hint: link the integration with $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: uniformly convergent where?

Comment: I changed my answer below to give a proof without using properties of the  gamma or zeta function.

Answer (score 2):

You may observe that, using a standard [integral representation of the gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), we have
$$
\int _0^{\infty }x^{s/2-1}e^{-\pi n^2x}dx=\frac{1}{n^s}\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)
$$ then your series rewrites
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^\infty x^{\frac{s}{2}-1}e^{-\pi n^{2}x}dx=\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}=\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s)
$$ and the convergence of the series is **uniform on each** $[a,b] \ni s$, $1<a<b$, since
$$
\left|\frac{1}{n^s}\right|\leq\frac{1}{n^a}, \quad n\geq1.
$$

Comment: So $M_n$ is $\frac{1}{n^{a}} $ here? does $a$ have to be less than s?

Comment: @OlivierOloa Of course, the series representation of the Riemann-Zeta function converges only when $\text{Re}(s)>1$.  So, we need to restrict $s$ in this problem such that $\text{Re}(s)>1$.

Comment: No, the series does not converge uniformly on $[a,\infty), $ simply because each of those integrals $\to \infty$ at $\infty.$ We do get uniform convergence on each $[a,b], 1<a<b<\infty.$

Comment: @zhw. Assume $s>0$. Please, I think you are not right saying that each integral $\to +\infty$, we rather have $\displaystyle \int _0^{\infty }x^{s/2-1}e^{-\pi n^2x}dx=\frac{1}{n^s}\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2) \to 0$, as $n \to +\infty$, or I'm missing something...

Comment: for each $n,$ $ \lim_{s\to \infty} \int _0^{\infty }x^{s/2-1}e^{-\pi n^2x}dx = \infty.$ No series of functions, each of which is unbounded on a set, can converge uniformly on that set.

Comment: @zhw.You are talking about $s \to +\infty$ (not $n \to +\infty$), you are then right! I will edit my answer, thanks.

Comment: @OlivierOloa would this then mean I can interchange sum and integral?

Answer (score 2):

Lemma: For any fixed $a>0,$

$$\lim_{p\to \infty}\int_0^\infty x^pe^{-ax}\, dx = \infty.$$

Proof: The integral is greater than

$$\int_1^2 x^p e^{-ax}\  dx \ge e^{-2a}\int_1^2 x^p\ dx = e^{-2a}\cdot\frac{2^{p+1}-1}{(p+1)}.$$

The last expression $\to \infty$ as $p\to \infty.$

In your problem, let $f_n(s)= \int_0^\infty x^{s/2-1}e^{-\pi n^2x}\,dx.$ You wonder  if $\sum_n f_n(s)$ converges uniformly on $(1,\infty).$ It doesn't. Why? The lemma shows each $f_n(s) \to \infty$ as $s\to \infty.$ So each $f_n$ is unbounded on $(1,\infty).$ Elementary fact: No series of unbounded bounded functions on a set can converge uniformly on that set.

Now you also bring up the question of whether sum and integral can be interhanaged in this problem. They can. A simple way to see that is the monotone convergence theorem, a corollary of which says, to be brief: If each $f_n$ is nonnegative, then $\sum_n \int f_n = \int (\sum_n f_n).$

Comment: The exponent on $x$ is fixed and doea not approach infinity in the original post.

Comment: How did you arrive at that? It certainly wasn't stated. The OP asks whether the sum converges uniformly. The $n$th summand should then be a function. Of what? Of $s$ of course.

Comment: I don't see a limit on the parameter $s$.  Am working on a "smart phone" so apology if I missed something.